# "Trying to get property of non object" error in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel 5.1 and I'm quite confused why I keep on getting this error. I have tried researching about this problem but nothing seems to solve my problem. It only gives me more errors.

It's really weird since when I try to `dd()` the variable it returns everything I need.

```
public function custInfo(Request $request)
{

    $search_custname = $request->input('cust_name');

    $customer_info = \DB::table('tblCustIndividual AS a')
            ->leftJoin('tblJobOrder AS b', 'a.strIndivID', '=', 'b.strJO_CustomerFK')
            ->leftJoin('tblJOPayment AS c', 'b.strJobOrderID', '=', 'c.strTransactionFK')
            ->select('a.strIndivID', \DB::raw('CONCAT(a.strIndivFName, " ", a.strIndivMName, " ", a.strIndivLName) AS fullname'), 'b.*', 'c.*')
            ->where(\DB::raw('CONCAT(a.strIndivFName, " ", a.strIndivMName, " ", a.strIndivLName)'), '=', $search_custname)
            ->first();



    return view('transaction-billingpayment-individual')
            ->with('search_custname', $search_custname)
            ->with('customer_info', $customer_info);
}
```

[here's the screenshot of the dd()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPCvj.png)

Comment: remove first from the query and try. Also share transaction-bullingpayment-individual view code so we can get idea

Comment: @if(isset($customer_info))          @foreach($customer_info as $customer)
 <div class="col s6">
  <div style="color:black" class="col s12">     
   <div class="col s5" style="color:teal; margin-top:4%"><b>Customer Name:</b></div>            
   <div class="col s7" style="color:black; margin-top:3%; padding:0; font-size:18px"><b>{{ $customer->fullname }}</b></div>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: Sorry.I dont think I can send an image. But in my view I used {{$customer->fullname}} to access the data I passed from the controller

Comment: remove the foreach and try to access full name like `{{ $customer_info ->fullname }}`

Comment: Try this

`if (!$search_custname->isEmpty()){ 
  // add your query here
}`  May be you are trying to get something that doesn't exisit.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you! Finally, it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Regarding your now deleted question, please note [that requesting urgency](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) is a downvote attractor here. Also, please always post code and JSON as a text block - there is a formatting especially for the purpose. Hope that helps!

Comment: (If you would replace the two images with text blocks here, even though the question is solved, that may help prevent it from being put on hold. Thanks).

Comment: Thank you halfer! I will take note of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case remove `foreach` and try to access it like

```
{{ $customer_info->fullname }}
```

Or

Try this

```
if (!$search_custname->isEmpty()){ 
  // your query
}
```

Actually `fisrt()` returns Model or null, so always add a check there.